Divide a number like 100 into 12 rows (cells) without decimals and the sum of the 12 rows is 100
I need a formula that splits a number like arrays into 12 rows and no decimal places (0.00) in each divided cell.

How can I solve this only from a formula (no vbs)?
As seen in the Image: A2 = 100
From B3 to B14, all amounts are 8.33. Instead of 8.33, I need a round number as shown in column C.

On each row the formula needs to be :
 INT(Amount / 12) + IF(MOD(Amount, 12) >= ROW() - Offset, 1, 0)

Explanation :
The first part of the formula gets the average of your value and keeps the Integer part.
Then using MOD and the number of the current row you can calculate if you need to adjust or not by 1. The remainder tells you how many rows need to be adjusted. So checking the current Row number and comparing to the MOD will tell you if you need to adjust the current row.

Amount : The number to divide in 12 cells.
Offset : The number of cells before your first cell to adjust the row count.


Nice one; much cleaner than my suggestion.  NB: To have the higher numbers at the end of the list (per Op's screenshot) just tweak this to =INT(Amount / DivideBy) + IF(DivideBy-MOD(Amount, DivideBy) < ROW() - Offset, 1, 0)

Another possible solution:

Where:
D2        -> =INT(B2/12)
E2        -> =12-MOD(B2;12)
D3        -> =IF(C3>$E$2;$D$2+1;$D$2)
D4 to D13 -> dragged from D3

Explanation:

INT(B2/12): integer part of "amount" divided by 12;

12-MOD(B2;12): twelve minus remainder after "amount" is divided by twele.This result indicates how many cells will receive "amount"/12 + 1 and

IF(C3>$E$2;$D$2+1;$D$2) ... IF(C13>$E$2;$D$2+1;$D$2): Puts in D3-D13 "amount"/12 or "amount"/12 + 1



Jean-Samuel Girard's answer is much cleaner & more efficient than mine - so I recommend that instead.  Leaving my answer here as an alternate option in case it's of use/interest to anyone, but it's overcomplex and inefficient.

The below assumes that you have 100 in a cell named Amount (A1 in the screenshot) and 12 in a cell named DivideBy (A2 in the screenshot).  In cell B1 you'd then have this formula, which you copy down to B12, allowing non-anchored references to update with the relative row number:
=IF(ROW()=1,FLOOR(Amount/DivideBy,1),FLOOR((Amount-SUM(INDIRECT("$B$1:$B"&(ROW()-1))))/(DivideBy-ROWS(INDIRECT("$B$1:$B"&(ROW()-1)))),1))


Explanation

The If statement is there to cover the first result; there is no row 0 so the else part of the formula would cause an issue if we applied it here, so we want to avoid that calculation.  Instead for our first row we just return the result as FLOOR(Amount/DivideBy,1).
The else part comes into play for every subsequent row

The FLOOR(...,1) just says to round down to the nearest integer.
The INDIRECT("$B$1:$B"&(ROW()-1) we use in a couple of places; it's the equivelent of writing $B$1:$B0, except that $B0 is invalid so produces a #NAME error, even if we copy the formula to the next row (i.e. where it would become $B1, but doesn't as Excel didn't recognise $B0 as a cell reference, so didn't increment it).  If we had a header row we could have done this as then we don't need to worry about row 0, but indirect works regardless of header rows.
The Amount-Sum part says to calculate what's remaining after what we've calculated above; so in B2 it's 92, in B3 it's 84, 76, 68, and so on
The DivideBy-Rows part works out how many cells are left; so in B2 it's 11, then 10, 9, 8 and so on.
By dividing Amount-Sum by DivideBy-Rows each time we're calculating the even distribution of what's left by the number of spaces left; if the numbers were perfectly divisible (e.g. if DivideBy were 10 this would be the same result each time (i.e. 100/10=10, (100-10)/9=10, (100-20)/8=10, etc.).  Because it's not perfectly divisible though, and we're rounding down, we get 100/12=8, (100-8)/11=8, etc; when we get to (100-54)/4 the rounding difference then pushes the result up to 9, where it stays for the remaining rows.




Split Integer

Make it dynamic (spill) using the SEQUENCE function (since Excel 2021).

Remainder Distributed at the Bottom
Formula
=LET(integer,100,parts,12,
    INT(integer/parts)+(SEQUENCE(parts)>(parts-MOD(integer,parts))))

Lambda Function (Name Manager)
Formula (e.g. SplitInteger)
=LAMBDA(integer,parts,
    INT(integer/parts)+(SEQUENCE(parts)>(parts-MOD(integer,parts))))

Usage
=SplitInteger(100,12)

Remainder Distributed at the Top
Formula
=LET(integer,100,parts,12,
    INT(integer/parts)+(SEQUENCE(parts)<=(MOD(integer,parts))))

